# android gridview entries starts from bottom to up

Tags: android, gridview, bottom-up

I have a gridview which height is half of the phone's height and aligned to parent's bottom like below images, *(numofcolums=1 i need it that way of other reasons)*

But i also need the items in the gridview starts from bottom to up like second image

**How can i achieve this with android gridview?**
*Is it possible or do i have to design custom implementation similar to gridview?*

Thanks

[image: android gridview bottom to up]

Comment: Did you try to set the gravity property of the GridView?

Comment: Yes, i tried gv.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); but it didn't worked

Comment: Create Relative Layout that takes half the screen, and put the GridVIew inside and set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: thanks but it makes only gridview align to bottom, i already achieved that, i need items of the gridview starts from bottom and grow to top

Comment: I'm in the same situation ! Did you find a solution ?